# EfCore 3 and Owned Type in same table, How do you set owned instance

Tags: entity-framework-core

How do you set owned type instance with efcore3?

In following example an exception is raised

> 'The entity of type 'Owned' is sharing the table 'Principals' with
>   entities of type 'Principal', but there is no entity of this type with
>   the same key value that has been marked as 'Added'.

If I set Child property inline savechanges doesn't update child properties

I can't find any example about this. I tried with several efcore3 builds and daily builds. What didn't I understand?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace TestEF
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var id = Guid.NewGuid();

      using (var db = new Ctx())
      {
        db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        db.Database.EnsureCreated();

        var p = new Principal {Id = id};
        db.Principals.Add(p);
        db.SaveChanges();
      }

      using (var db = new Ctx())
      {
        var p = db.Principals.Single(o => o.Id == id);
        p.Child = new Owned();
        p.Child.Prop1 = "Test2";
        p.Child.Prop2 = "Test2";
        db.SaveChanges();
      }
    }

    public class Principal
    {
      public Guid Id { get; set; }
      public Owned Child { get; set; }
    }

    public class Owned
    {
      public string Prop1 { get; set; }
      public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Ctx : DbContext
    {
      public DbSet<Principal> Principals { get; set; }

      protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
      {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TestEF;Trusted_Connection=True;Persist Security Info=true");
      }

      protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder mb)
      {
        var emb = mb.Entity<Principal>();
        emb
          .OwnsOne(o => o.Child, cfg =>
          {
            cfg.Property(o => o.Prop1).HasMaxLength(30);
            //cfg.WithOwner();
          });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, filed at https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/17422

As a workaround you could make the child appear as modified:

```
db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
var childEntry = db.Entry(p.Child);
childEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

`_context.Update(entity);`

This will update all the owned properties so SaveChanges() updates them, too.